# Error in hibernate-> org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: The given object has a null identifier

Tags: javascript, eclipse, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have tried all the possible websites but couldn't find a solution for this. The different case here is that my primary key is of string type and i cannot even use auto generation using sequences. This problem is occurring when I'm trying to update the data in the table. 
This is my Model class:

```
    package com.pack1.model;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table (name="automation_test")
public class Config {

@Id
@Column(name="DATA_ID")
private String dataa_id;
private String r12_user_name    ;
private String r12_app_url;
private String r12_user_password;
private String p6_url;
private String p6_username;
private String p6_password;
private String dcp_url;
private String dcp_username;
private String dcp_password;
private String so_appurl;
private String so_appusername;
private String so_apppassword;
private String odsrefresh_url;
private String odsrefresh_username;
private String odsrefresh_password;

public String getDataa_id() {
    return dataa_id;
}
public void setDataa_id(String dataa_id) {
    this.dataa_id = dataa_id;
}
public String getR12_user_name() {
    return r12_user_name;
}
public void setR12_user_name(String r12_user_name) {
    this.r12_user_name = r12_user_name;
}
public String getR12_app_url() {
    return r12_app_url;
}
public void setR12_app_url(String r12_app_url) {
    this.r12_app_url = r12_app_url;
}
public String getR12_user_password() {
    return r12_user_password;
}
public void setR12_user_password(String r12_user_password) {
    this.r12_user_password = r12_user_password;
}
public String getP6_url() {
    return p6_url;
}
public void setP6_url(String p6_url) {
    this.p6_url = p6_url;
}
public String getP6_username() {
    return p6_username;
}
public void setP6_username(String p6_username) {
    this.p6_username = p6_username;
}
public String getP6_password() {
    return p6_password;
}
public void setP6_password(String p6_password) {
    this.p6_password = p6_password;
}
public String getDcp_url() {
    return dcp_url;
}
public void setDcp_url(String dcp_url) {
    this.dcp_url = dcp_url;
}
public String getDcp_username() {
    return dcp_username;
}
public void setDcp_username(String dcp_username) {
    this.dcp_username = dcp_username;
}
public String getDcp_password() {
    return dcp_password;
}
public void setDcp_password(String dcp_password) {
    this.dcp_password = dcp_password;
}
public String getSo_appurl() {
    return so_appurl;
}
public void setSo_appurl(String so_appurl) {
    this.so_appurl = so_appurl;
}
public String getSo_appusername() {
    return so_appusername;
}
public void setSo_appusername(String so_appusername) {
    this.so_appusername = so_appusername;
}
public String getSo_apppassword() {
    return so_apppassword;
}
public void setSo_apppassword(String so_apppassword) {
    this.so_apppassword = so_apppassword;
}
public String getOdsrefresh_url() {
    return odsrefresh_url;
}
public void setOdsrefresh_url(String odsrefresh_url) {
    this.odsrefresh_url = odsrefresh_url;
}
public String getOdsrefresh_username() {
    return odsrefresh_username;
}
public void setOdsrefresh_username(String odsrefresh_username) {
    this.odsrefresh_username = odsrefresh_username;
}
public String getOdsrefresh_password() {
    return odsrefresh_password;
}
public void setOdsrefresh_password(String odsrefresh_password) {
    this.odsrefresh_password = odsrefresh_password;
}
}
```

This is my DAO:

```
package com.pack1.dao;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.SQLQuery;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.pack1.model.Test;
import com.pack1.model.Config;
@Repository("testiDao")
public class TestDAOImpl implements TestDAO{
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public List getAllDetails()
{



    SQLQuery query=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("select * from automation_test");
    query.addEntity("automation_test",Test.class);
    List list=query.list();
    return list;

}

@Override
public void insert(Config cg)
{
    System.out.println("Request");
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(cg);
    System.out.println("Response");



}




}
```

This is my Controller:

```
package com.pack1.controller;

import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.pack1.model.Test;
import com.pack1.model.Config;
import com.pack1.service.TestService;

@Controller
public class TestController {

@Autowired 
private TestService testService;


@RequestMapping(value="/start",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String setupForm(@ModelAttribute Config con1,Map<String,Object> map)
{
    Config con=new Config();
    map.put("con", con);
    return "config";
}


@RequestMapping(value="/doCon",method=RequestMethod.GET)
   public String doInsert(@ModelAttribute Config con1, BindingResult result,@RequestParam String action,Map<String,Object> map)
   {

    Config cg=new Config();
    if(action.toLowerCase().equals("submit"))
    {
            testService.insert(cg);

    }
    map.put("con",cg);
    return "config";
    }   

@RequestMapping(value="/config",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String doback(Map<String,Object> map)
{
    Config con=new Config();
    map.put("con", con);
    return "config";

}

}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: The given object has a null identifier: com.pack1.model.Config
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Kindly help as I'm stuck on this since a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/doCon",method=RequestMethod.GET)
   public String doInsert(@ModelAttribute Config con1, BindingResult result,@RequestParam String action,Map<String,Object> map)
   {

    Config cg=new Config();
    if(action.toLowerCase().equals("submit"))
    {
            testService.insert(cg);

    }
    map.put("con",cg);
    return "config";
    }
```

cg has a `null` id that's why you are getting that exception when executing

`testService.insert(cg);`

Maybe you mean :

`testService.insert(con1);` instead and make sure con1's`dataa_id` is not `null`